# Finding a program running as AppImage

Tags: command-line, java, appimage

In order to launch it from java with some command-line parameters, I'm trying to localize programmatically a certain application ran as AppImage. In my case it is the [MuseScore application](https://musescore.org/fr/download#AppImage-(recommended)).

I installed it with the command `./MuseScore*.AppImage install`.

I first tried from a terminal to localize that application using different options [`dpkg-query -L musescore`](https://superuser.com/a/173347/353949) and [`which musescore`](https://superuser.com/a/292759/353949). I had no response.

In Windows, I can either search the registry or parse the result of a command-line command `assoc ".myext"`.

Then, in Java, write use a

```
String program=null;
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c assoc \".myext\"");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()))) {
    program=reader.readLine();
}
```

How could I do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure. Installing and running this application are not the issue (`libfuse2` is installed and "install" has just created some subfolders in the user's home folder). 

The question: is *which command can use in a Termincal (e.g.) to retriece where this AppImage is located ?* Because my java application needs to call that AppImage with some other parameters. Actually I'm looking to the equivalent in Linux to Window's `assoc ".mscx"` or the equivalent of searching the Windows Registry for the key `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MuseScore.mscz\shell\open\command"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One can achieve this in 3 steps:

1. (Optional) Retrieve the mime-type of a file managed by the searched application

Command: `xdg-mime query filetype path\to\a\file`

Result: `application/x-y-z`

2. Search for the application handling this mime-type:

Command: `xdg-mime query default application/x-y-z`

Result: `someapplication.desktop`

3. Search for that desktop file and extract the exec path:
   Search the files in the folders listed in `XDG_DATA_DIRS` as well as `/home/myuser/.local/share/applications/`.
   If found, parse it as a regular Property file and search for the `Exec` property

See https://gist.github.com/lgvr123/cdeb8f432ddfdc0ae56ce23e71f1b177

4. Alternatively, if (3) failed : Search for the application locally:

Command: `which someapplication` (Please note that ".desktop" has been removed from the result of step (2) )

Result: `/home/myuser/.local/bin/someapplication` or an empty string if the application is not presente locally.

Comment: This may work or not work. It will only give you the correct result if the application you are looking for was set as default application for the mime-type.

Comment: Good observation. I combined both approaches in my java code. First this one. Then, if it has not returned the expected application, I'm searching the application in expected locations.

Comment: Instead of using `which` it might be better to look in the `exec`-line of the desktop-file, this will tell you exactly where the executable is located.

Comment: For me it worked. So it remains my solution. Although I'll check your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`./MuseScore*.AppImage install` moves the appimage to `~/.local/bin`.

A command named `musescore` is not created thus the which-command you used was useless in this case. `dpkg` will not give you any clue either because you didn't use `dpkg` to install it. The installation also created some symlinks to the appimage named `mscore-portable` and `musescore-portable`.

You can use the `find`-command to locate the appimage. I didn't need to do that, I simply read the output of the install-command.

To run the appimge from commandline you need to specify full path to the appimage or one of the symlinks if `~/.local/bin` is not in your PATH.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to know where the AppImage binary (or any file) is located, run the following command.

```
find / -name "*.AppImage" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

The command `find` will search root `/`, and then `ls -l` will display the path to the file(s). If the filename has changed, adjust accordingly.

---

As others have pointed out, using `dpkg-query -L musescore` does not yield any results because the binary was not installed using the package manager; thus, `dpkg` does not "know" its existence.

And using `which musescore` also does not yield results because the AppImage is not in a directory defined in the PATH, nor is the filename of the executable binary, i.e., the binary is `MuseScore.AppImage` and not `musescore`.